# How to code a bot to send a message if they ping the owner

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make a bot say a message when the owner is pinged, a bit like this.

User: @JetSamsterGaming please respond.

Bot: (deletes message) @User You cannot ping JetSamsterGaming!

Thanks!

Comment: Add an on message listener. Check if each message content includes the ping. Respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) has a property called [`mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions) ([`MessageMentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions)) which contains all the mentions (roles, channels, members, users).

You can use [`MessageMentions.has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=has) to check if the owner was mentioned in the message.

---

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

const ownerId = "ID";

client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;

    if (message.mentions.has(ownerId)) {
        await message.delete();
        message.reply(`You cannot ping my owner!`);
    };
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_AUTH_TOKEN);
```

Comment: Thank you! This has really helped.

Answer (score -1):

```
//setup stuff

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

//real code

client.on('message', msg => {                 //when a message is sent
  if(msg.content.includes("<@!id>")){//checks if they pinged the owner.
// you can get the id by right-clicking the profile and copy id. you will need to turn on developer mode
   msg.channel.send('You cannot ping that user');
   msg.delete()                                //deletes the message
  }
});

client.login('id');
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!